# Laravel Mix jQuery no está definido

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, laravel-mix

Actualmente vengo desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel 5.6 y me encuentro con el problema de que tras compilar (correctamente) algunas librerías con Laravel Mix, no puedo utilizar jQuery.

El error que se muestra en consola es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

La configuración de mi archivo webpack.min.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.styles([
  'resources/assets/css/main.css',
  'resources/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css'
], 'public/css/app.css')
.scripts([
  'resources/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
  'resources/assets/js/popper.min.js',
  'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'resources/assets/js/main.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Parte de la vista blade donde utilizo jQuery:

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn_demo').click(function(){...});
    </script>
@endsection
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionar este problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Me pasaba lo mismo. El app.js NO tiene que tener defer si lo estas emebebiendo el head.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ponle esto en bootstrap.js:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Que hace ese código? Las respuestas de solo código no son bien recibidas.

Comment: se supone que soluciona lo que pide. Requiere jQuery y define la variable para que globalmente lo reconozca..